# Pywin32 alternative or a way to cast PyIDL to PIDL

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, pywin32, activepython

So apparently I have uncovered [a bug in pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190531/how-to-use-shgetfileinfo-with-shgfi-pidl-in-python). Now I can't use the `win32com.shell.shell.SHGetFileInfo` function with `win32com.shell.shellcon.SHGFI_PIDL` flag.

What I want to do is to enumerate the desktop icons (all of them, including the virtual ones) and get the icons themselves (the images). I was trying to do this (before I knew about the bug) using something like:

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
desktop = shell.SHGetDesktopFolder()
enum = desktop.EnumObjects(None, shellcon.SHCONTF_FOLDERS | shellcon.SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS)
for pidl in enum:
    shell_info = shell.SHGetFileInfo(desktop_pidl, 0, shellcon.SHGFI_PIDL | shellcon.SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | shellcon.SHGFI_ICON | shellcon.SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME)
```

So how can I do this without `shell.SHGetFileInfo` with PIDL? The problem with using ctypes for just this is that `enum` contains PyIDLs which are specific to pywin32. Is there a way to cast PyIDL to regular PIDL that I can use with ctypes? Or is there a way to do this without PyIDL entirely?

In the worst case I can use ctypes for all of this (including the `SHGetDesktopFolder` and `EnumObjects`) but that's really long and kinda feels like reinventing the wheel.

Thank you!

Comment: I will revise my answer to your original question. This is straight forward using `shell.PIDLAsString`.

Comment: It works! I didn't know about this function. Thank you!